# Can't install package RWeka

Tags: r, macos, rweka

I am trying to install the RWeka package.

```
install.packages("RWeka")
```

When I do this I get the following errors.

```
 ** package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 Need at least Java version 1.7/7.0.
     ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RWeka’
 * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RWeka’
     Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/qq/lyrzyp0119x1zmld972mbfz00000gn/T/Rtmp9xnRxx/downloaded_packages’
```

I have tried updating/altering Java but that does not seem to be the problem

Here is the session info:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: do you have trouble installing any other packages?

Comment: Actually no, I've had no problem installing other packages so far. I recently updated to a newer version of R. RWeka worked before the update.

Comment: what version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: also have you tried downloading the binaries and installing from local source?

Comment: I installed java 6 from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US)

Comment: I think you need Java 8 -Java 6 is legacy....RWeka works on my build and I have Java 8 installed. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html for download

Comment: I believe I installed from source by default. I'm not sure how to try binary. I get this notice ' There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
RWeka 0.4-26 0.4-29             FALSE '

Comment: Yesss! Upgrading to Java 8 fixed it. Thank you this has been really annoying.

Comment: @PHH13 you can add this as an answer to your question and mark it as solved. This makes it clear that this is solved and more clearly shows what solved your issues (and gets you some rep :)).